# Using chrome to detect memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I'm having troble with memory leaks on the page. Here is how my time line looks like:

[image]

I know which JS function causes leaks, but I can't figure out which part of it does it.
When I try to take heap snapshot in Profile menu - there is complyteley different information - it shows, that I'm using only 28MB of memory (how it's compared to timeline numbers??)

[image]

**Is there a way to find out what exact nodes are created and by what part of the js function?**

Answer (score 0):

If the peak memory usage is not growing throughout time then I would not deem it a memory leak as the Javascript engine is free to choose when to garbage collect. It is more efficient for the engine to allow the program to run freely while it periodically performs a mark and sweep of unused objects to clear it up.

I can't answer the other question about the mismatch in size I'm afraid.